# Counter example regarding bounded functions.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, fake-proofs

[image]

I feel that I completely missed the point in this question, as I didn't even use / don't know how to use the fact that $a,b$ are removable discontinuities..
Does that mean I need to construct a function $g$ that will cover the scenario regarding the discontinuity points?

> Counter example:
>
> Consider the function $f: R\ ➜ R$ , $f\left(x\right)\ =\ \frac{1}{x}$
>
> Let $(a,b) = (o,1)$. Note that $f$ is continuous on $(0,1)$.
>
> $\lim _{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=∞$
>
> $\lim _{x\to 1^-}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=1$
>
> Since the one sided limits tends to $∞$, $f$ is not bounded on
> $(0,1)$.

Comment: How $0$ is a point of removable discontinuity in your prescribed function?

Comment: You're right it isn't, completely ignored that fact.. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Definition:** A function $f$ is said to have a **removable discontinuity** at $a \in \mathbb{R}$, if $\lim_\limits{x \to a} f(x)$ exists finitely and $\lim_\limits{x \to a} f(x)\neq f(a)$.

By this definition, see $\lim_\limits{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}$ is not finite. So it is not a counterexample.

Letting $\lim_\limits{x \to a}f(x)=p$ and $\lim_\limits{x \to b}f(x)=q$, one can construct a function $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$g(x):= \begin{cases}
          f(x) & x \in (a,b) \\
          p    & x=a \\
          q    & x=b \\
         \end{cases}$$
Now $g$ is a bounded function in $[a,b]$.
(*this follows from the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem which in turn follows from* **lub-axiom**)

$g$ is bounded $\implies$ $\exists \ M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x) \leq M$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ $\implies f(x) \leq M$ for all $x \in (a,b)$, i.e $f$ is bounded in (a,b).

Comment: Nice thanks! I've seen our PA do something similar in the recitation and I think after seeing your example it's really clearer now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $c=\frac{a+b}2$.
By definition of "removable discontinuity", there exists a function $g\colon[a,b)\to \Bbb R$ such that $g|_{(a,b)}=f$ and $g$ is continiuous at $a$. it follows that $g$ is continuous, hence is continuous on the interval $[a,c]$, by compactness is bounded there, and $f$ is also bounded on $(a,c]$.

Similarly, the removable discontinuity at $b$ shows that $f$ is bounded on $[c,b)$, hence $f$ is bounded on all of $(a,b)$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Can you expand on why a function g exists? I can't find an explanation in our course book..

Comment: @MathCurious Because $g$ is just $f$ but with the discontinuity point removed.